# C# MVC5 include custom error page into masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

we have several `c# mvc5` apps. For having a centralized point of dealing with unhandled exceptions I would like to have a custom error page in my masterpage and use `global.asax` (in every app) to redirect to `~Shared/Error` in case of unhandled exception caused in any of my applictions.

- added `Error.cshtml` to my shared folder in masterpage
- added `ActionResult` `Error()` to `SharedController.cs` in masterpage

```
namespace MasterpageMvc.Controllers
{
    [Localizable]
    public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        private SharedViewModel SharedViewModel { get; } = new SharedViewModel();

        ...

        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

- made a NugetPack of my masterpage and added NugetPack to my AppX
- disabled adding Error filter (AppX)

```
namespace ApplicationX
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

- added Application_Error in global.asax.cs (AppX)

```
namespace ApplicationX
{

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        protected void Application_Error()
        {
            // Log error to eventlog using NLog
            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

- redirected custom error in web.config (AppX) to ~/Shared/Error

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Shared/Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Shared/Error" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Error I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Masterpage/Error.cshtml
```

Any help is highly appreciated!
TIA acki

Answer (score 0):

Put in your action the name of the view, and if you need the name of master page as second argument

```
 public ActionResult Error()
 {
            return View("Errors");
 }
```

Comment: doesn't work Error.cshtml is never part of the nuget pack